# The magnitude of $5 \vec u + 4 \vec v + 2 \vec w$ where $\vec u,\vec v,\vec w$ are mutually perpendicular and of unit magnitude

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Of course the answer is $\sqrt{25+16+4} = \sqrt{45}$.

It is easy to see it when we consider the (extended) Pythagorean Theorem, or even more easily just taking $\vec u = \hat i, \ \vec v = \hat j$ and $\vec w = \hat k$.

But how do we show it without geometry and for the general case? For instance using dot/vector product?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "without geometry", given that the proof of the Pythagorean theorem in higher dimensions is itself done algebraically by writing the square of the norm as an inner product and using induction?

Comment: @JoshChen , I wanted to say without having to draw (a rectangular prism, for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By brute force:

$$\begin{align}
\|5u+4v+2w\|^2 &= \langle 5u+4v+2w,5u+4v+2w\rangle \\ &= 25 \langle u,u\rangle + 16\langle v,v\rangle + 4\langle w,w\rangle + 2\left(20\langle u,v\rangle + 10\langle u,w\rangle + 8\langle v,w\rangle\right) \\ &= 25 \cdot 1 + 16 \cdot 1 + 4 \cdot 1 + 2(20 \cdot 0 + 10\cdot 0+ 8\cdot 0) \\ &= 25+16+4 \\ &= 45,
\end{align}$$

so $\|5u+4v+2w\| = \sqrt{45}$. The point is to use the Pythagoeran theorem to reduce these boring computations.

Comment: To improve formatting, delete blank space between dollars and formula.

Comment: @choco thanks! ${}$